# Django: show the count of related objects in admin list_display

Tags: python, django

I would like to show the count of related objects in django's list_display property.
for example we have a category field and we want to show how many blog posts are posted in this category

I have tried this so far:

admin.py:

```
from .models import Category

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def category_post_count(self, obj):
        return obj.post_set.count
category_post_count.short_description = "Posts Count"

list_display = ['category', 'category_post_count']
```

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=False)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`.count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#count) is a function so you have to call it by appending parentheses `()` at the end:

```
def category_post_count(self, obj):
    return obj.post_set.count()
```

Comment: Hey, I have a separate question regarding this. I am trying to learn Django. Can you point me to the proper documentation that explains why this works. (i.e. this method of showing total count of ForeignKey object records in admin. I am interested in explanation / documentation on function category_post_count). Thanks

Comment: @Deep you can check this out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: @romain answer should be the top answer. It's the second one at the time of writing this. This one is really inefficient.

Answer (score 33):

Although the accepted answer will produce the expected result, this is not how it should be done in most cases because it will generate a "n+1" problem, a.k.a one more sql query per row.

You should modify your admin class (or manager if you need it in more situations than just the admin) to retrieve a count annotation (which is django's term for aggregate columns) and then use this value. It will compute the count in the main select query, avoiding generation of non necessary queries.

```
...
from django.db.models import Count
...

@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [..., 'post_count']

    ...

    def post_count(self, obj):
        return obj.post_count

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        queryset = queryset.annotate(post_count=Count("post"))
        return queryset
```

Comment: note, if you were like me and needed the count of distinct posts, `Count("post", distinct=True)`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count.distinct

Comment: also, you can traverse relationships like `Count("post__category", distinct=True)`

Comment: Add this property to the class to make the column sortable :   
`post_count.admin_order_field = 'post_count'`